# RBAC with INNER JOIN and lookup tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, rbac

I am working on a RBAC user authentication system, and this is what I've come up with.

Here is my logic:

**1)** find $userAccount's role/group (user_role) by means of the `id` (the PK)

**2)** check the role has permission for the $webModule they are one (role_object_method)

**3)** check the website section allows for desired action (object_method)

**4)** return true if > 0 rows are returned, else return false

**query**: called from function hasPermission($userAccount, $webModule, $webOperation) that returns a bool

```
SELECT `user`.`account,
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `user_role`
ON `user`.`id` = `user_role`.`user_id`
AND `user`.`account` = '$userAccount'
INNER JOIN `role_object_method`
ON `role_object_method`.`role_group` = `user_role`.`role_group`
INNER JOIN `object_method`
ON `role_object_method`.`object_module` = `object_method`.`object_module`
AND `role_object_method`.`method_operation` = `object_method`.`method_operation`
AND `object_method`.`object_module` = '$webModule'
AND `object_method`.`method_operation` = '$webOperation';
```

I'm confident on the tables, but am new to performing INNER JOIN. Does the query I wrote perform the 4 steps I am desiring?

My testing so far has yielded the result I want, but I would like to run the query by those more familiar with using INNER JOIN.

Thank you.

**Additional Information**

I create 4 lookup tables:

**user**: stores user registrations, `id` is PK INT AUTO_INCREMENT

**role**: stores roles (user, admin, owner)

**object**: table of different sections of the website (public area, member area, admin area)

**method**: table of operations that can be done to content (view, add, publish, etc)

and 3 tables comprised from them:

**user_role**: stores "groups" assigned to users

**object_method**: stores each sections abilities (i.e. if the member area is under maintenance, can remove the row "member", "publish" temporarily)

**role_object_method**: stores the permissions each group has for each section of the website

There are 3 variables that are related:

**$userAccount**: provided by $_SESSION variable after successful user login

**$webModule**: provided by webpage as user visits the site

**$webOperation**: coded in

user

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`account` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

role

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
`group` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`group`)
);
```

object

```
CREATE TABLE `object` (
`module` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`module`)
);
```

method

```
CREATE TABLE `method` (
`operation` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`operation`)
);
```

user_role

```
CREATE TABLE `user_role` (
`user_id` INT ,
`role_group` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `role_group`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`role_group`) REFERENCES `role` (`group`)
);
```

object_method

```
CREATE TABLE `object_method` (
`object_module` CHAR,
`method_operation` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`object_module`, `method_operation`),
FOREIGN KEY (`object_module`) REFERENCES `object` (`module`),
FOREIGN KEY (`method_operation`) REFERENCES `method` (`operation`)
);
```

role_object_method

```
CREATE TABLE `role_object_method` (
`role_group` CHAR,
`object_module` CHAR,
`method_operation` CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (`role_group`, `object_module`, `method_operation`),
FOREIGN KEY (`role_group`) REFERENCES `role` (`group`),
FOREIGN KEY (`object_module`) REFERENCES `object` (`module`),
FOREIGN KEY (`method_operation`) REFERENCES `method` (`operation`)
);
```

Comment: I guess there's no need of linked table "object_method" because you are already linking with respect to role in role_object_method.

Comment: Why don't you use a framework? There are plenty to choose from e.g. RBAC or ABAC (attribute-based access control)

Comment: In the future I may use a framework (been eyeing Zend myself). For now, I'm interested in learning how to create the RBAC code myself to help me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion, if you remove the extra linked table `object_method` your query will change to this.

```
SELECT `user`.`account`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `user_role`
ON `user`.`id` = `user_role`.`user_id`
AND `user`.`account` = '$userAccount'
INNER JOIN `role_object_method`
ON `role_object_method`.`role_group` = `user_role`.`role_group`
AND `role_object_method`.`object_module` = '$webModule'
AND `role_object_method`.`method_operation` = '$webOperation';
```

Comment: Thank you Hatim, I appreciate you looking over my code and giving me your suggestion with code. I ran some tests with your code, and found that it works beautifully, but it did not allow for "3) check the website section allows for desired action (object_method)". Which makes sense since that section was removed.